# Concatenate two strings row-wise in python

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

I have two strings as below:

```
comstr = ['year', 'doy', 'd_lon', 'd_lat']
datstr = ['2015', '112', '1.78218', '1.78218']
```

How can I concatenate the two strings? I want the result as below:

```
'year', 'doy', 'd_lon', 'd_lat'      # 1st row
'2015', '112', '1.78218', '1.78218'  # 2nd row
```

Comment: those are _lists_. You can use `" ".join("'{}'".format(x) for x in comstr)`

Comment: Those are lists, whose elements are lists. Also, the result you want is supposed to be a list?

Comment: @JuanT: list of strings.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre : I think you missed a `,`

Comment: @EricDuminil correct.

Answer (score 0):

You could use :

```
com_list = ['year', 'doy', 'd_lon', 'd_lat']
dat_list = ['2015', '112', '1.78218', '1.78218']

for strings in [com_list, dat_list] :
    print(", ".join(["'%s'" % string for string in strings]))
```

It outputs :

```
'year', 'doy', 'd_lon', 'd_lat'
'2015', '112', '1.78218', '1.78218'
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I wouldn't rely on `repr` for that task.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: Updated. Why not?

Comment: I'm thinking that this is overkill. Besides, if newer versions of python change the `repr` for strings, your program becomes wrong. BTW: better do `", ".join(["'%s'" % string for string in strings])`. `join` works faster on listcomps.